# Batch alarm-file wont go off

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

Due to tremendous problems getting up in the morning i decided to write a batch-script that executes a specific file at a given time. However, it does not work when i leave my computer idle for a longer period, it seems like the loop itself does not loop anymore.

I cant understand what is causing this to not work because my screensaver and CPU/HDD-sleep is shut off.

Here is the code:

```
echo OFF

@echo Set hour for alarm:
set /p hour=
@echo Set minute for alarm:
set /p minute=

@echo alarm will ring at %hour% : %minute%

:waitDay
for /f "tokens=5-8 delims=:. " %%a in ('echo/^|time') do (
  set hh=%%a
)

IF %hh% GTR %hour% GOTO waitDay


:start
for /f "tokens=5-8 delims=:. " %%a in ('echo/^|time') do (
  set hh=%%a&set nn=%%b&set ss=%%c&set cs=%%d
)

IF %hh% LSS %hour% GOTO start
IF %nn% LSS %minute% GOTO start

cd \d C:
cd \d C:\Users\Oted\Desktop\Stuff\
"alarm.xspf"
```

Glad if anyone could help, i use Windows 7.

Comment: Please edit your question and include information about the operating system you use. Also add that informtion as a tag. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of running a loop constantly all night (thus using CPU and wasting energy and adding wear and tear on your system), why not use a Windows Scheduled Task to just launch your alarm at the  time it's supposed to go off? It's also much more convenient - you don't have to remember to set it, you can program it to only run certain days (eg., weekdays) or to run at different times on different days, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal

set /p exectime=Enter when you want the task to execute (HH:MM): 
set batchfilelocation=C:\Users\Oted\Desktop\Stuff\alarm.xspf

SCHTASKS /create /SC DAILY /TN "WAKEUP" /TR "%batchfilelocation%" /S %computername%
pause
endlocal

REM /SC allows for the following frequency schedules:
REM     MINUTE:     1 - 1439 minutes.
REM     HOURLY:     1 - 23 hours.
REM     DAILY:      1 - 365 days.
REM     WEEKLY:     weeks 1 - 52.
REM     ONCE:       No modifiers.
REM     ONSTART:    No modifiers.
REM     ONLOGON:    No modifiers.
REM     ONIDLE:     No modifiers.
REM     MONTHLY:    1 - 12, or FIRST, SECOND, THIRD, FOURTH, LAST, LASTDAY.
```

This was created by a friend, I just edited it to be relevant for this situation.

This will create a Scheduled Task for whatever time you want to wake up.

Originally created by [iesou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1083755/iesou)

Answer (score 0):

I have re-written your script so it is a little easier to read, and I think the issue you were having was to do with the 3 bottom lines.

You put `\d` instead of `/d` which means it wouldn't change directory, hence trying to run the file `alarm.xspf` would fail as it wouldn't be in the right folder.

```
@echo off
set /p hour=Set hour for alarm: 
set /p minute=Set minute for alarm: 
echo Alarm will ring at %hour%:%minute%

:waitDay
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ("%time%") do (
set hh=%%a
)

if %hh% gtr %hour% goto :waitDay

:start
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ("%time%") do (
set hh=%%a
set mm=%%b
set ss=%%c
set ms=%%d
)

if %hh% lss %hour% goto :start
if %mm% lss %minute% goto :start

C:\Users\Oted\Desktop\Stuff\alarm.xspf
```

Comment: Oh thank you sir!  I tried it and the issue still remains tho, i don't know if  it has anything to do with the batch-file itself. Perhaps its my computer that prevents  the script from keep running after a longer period.   Anyone has any suggestions to what this could be?

Comment: @user1862925 Possibly, it should work fine though I think. I do also think that there are better ways of scheduling an alarm though. If you want to do it from batch look at `schtasks /?` and `at /?` which will give you much easier options to schedule your alarm.